# How to use the redux in react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

i'm trying to make a simple application
where I have an inputText, and a button which will alert the value of inputText when pressed.

but I need to add redux to this process, where the value of the inputText will be stored first, and the value of the store will be alerted.

but when I tried, it didn't work for me.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. if someone can help me, it would be very nice..

here is my codes:

Store.js

```
import { createStore , applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducer from './Reducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
    let store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

    return store
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    phoneNumber: 0
}

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            return {
                ...state,
                phoneNumber: action.payload
            }
        default :
            return state

    }

}
```

Action.js

```
export function setLoginNumber(number) {
    return{
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: number
    };
}
```

this is the tes class where I build the page:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import setLogin from '../Redux/Action';
import reducer from '../Redux/Reducer';

class tes extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
            phoneNumber: "",
        }
    }

    funcAlert() {
        alert(this.props.number)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="phone number"
                    keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={phoneNumber => this.setState({ phoneNumber })}/>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.setLoginNumber(this.state.phoneNumber)}>
                    <Text>login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.funcAlert}>
                    <Text>Alert!</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        number: state.phoneNumber
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        setLoginNumber: (phoneNumber) => {
            dispatch(setLoginNumber(phoneNumber))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(tes);
```

Comment: in `mapStateToProps` you are mapping `state.number`, in the reducer you are updating `state.phoneNumber`

Comment: Change `number: state.number` to `number: state.phoneNumber`

Comment: oh yeah you're right, but it still throws me an error at the red screen emulator saying "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.phoneNumber')"

Comment: in render method try this.props.phoneNumber. you've mapped state to props

Comment: in constructor, change `state =  ....` to `this.state =  ....`

Comment: when I change this.state.phoneNumber to this.props.phoneNumber, the error change to "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setLoginNumber"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you exporting your reducer?

I noticed your action isn't `export default` and your import doesn't specify the `import {setLoginNumber} from '../Redux/Action'`. It will need to have one of the two to work.

did you happen to change the mapState to props function from:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { number: state.number } 
}
```

to:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) { 
    return { number: state.phoneNumber } 
}
```

It can be confusing with the word *state*, but it gets the current stores state which in your reducer is:

```
const initialState = { phoneNumber: 0 }
```

And finally *bind* **this** to the `funcAlert`. In the constructor you can go:

```
this.funcAlert = this.funcAlert.bind(this)
```

or

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.funcAlert.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: yeah I have changed it to export function Reducer(). still saying cant find variable: setLoginNumber

Comment: I noticed your action isn't `export default` and your import doesn't specify the `import {setLoginNumber} from '../Redux/Action'`

Comment: oh yeah you're right. I import it the wrong way.. But, I got another error, it says undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.number')

Comment: did you happen to change the mapState to props function from:
`function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        number: state.number
    }
}`
to:
`function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        number: state.phoneNumber
    }
}`
It can be confusing with the word *state*, but it gets the current stores state which in your reducer is:
`const initialState = {
    phoneNumber: 0
}`

Comment: yeah it's now {number: state.phoneNumber}

but to get its value, I just need to call the front name which is "number" right?

Comment: yeah in the component it looks right with `this.props.number` I am just re looking over it now.

Comment: I think the save to store process is already right after following your correction, when I pressed the button login, it didn't throw any error.

the error now come when I pressed the alert button which getting the data

Comment: try changing createStore from `let store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))` to this: `let store = createStore(reducer, {}, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))` I don't know if that will work.

Comment: it says undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.phoneNumber')

Comment: Oh I know what it is. you need to bind `this` to the `funcAlert`. In the constructor you can go `this.funcAlert = this.funcAlert.bind(this)` or `<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.funcAlert.bind(this)}>`

Comment: oh thanks Brenton!! that's it.. now it works very well.. thanks so much Brenton!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are updating the current state like so:

```
<TextInput placeholder="phone number"
   keyboardType="number-pad" 
   onChangeText={text => this.setState({ phoneNumber:text })}
/>
```

And also change your constructor to include `this` and bind your functions (as Brenton suggested) to `this` or else the function will try to look for a variable called `this`

```
 this.state = {
   phoneNumber: "",
 }
 this.funcAlert = this.funcAlert.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting where you have declared the Provider and bound the store to the app. Also as someone as mentioned in another response, please check if you have exported the reducer.

For your reference, here is a starter project with react, react-redux and thunk. 
https://github.com/mohitmutha/react-redux-router-thunk-starter